# Try iPad Shortcuts in Simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, uikeycommand

With iOS 9 Developers can add Shortcuts to an iPad App using [UIKeyCommand](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyCommand_class/). 
Those are typed on an external keyboard and a function reacts.

Is there a way to test those in the simulator on the mac?
Or show them like here:

[image]

Comment: Trying to figure this out myself here now.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the keyboard shortcuts for your UIResponder subclass (keyCommands variable) you need to make your object first responder. I do it like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    becomeFirstResponder()
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Holding down command on your keyboard should now pop up the shortcut-view.